# Delete image/blob content to reduce *.mdf file size?

Tags: sql-server

I have an old SQL Server database and find it unnecessary to keep old image files the users upload.

Currently the `.mdf` filesize is around 10 GB and database size is mainly blown up by the image files stored in each record row (I estimate 8GB are image files). If all blob/image files older than 1 year old are deleted. Is it possible to drastically reduce the `.mdf` filesize to 2-3 GB?

If this works, I'll schedule a script to delete all old blob/images at the end of each year, and just keep images for the past 12 months.

Comment: So you're going to reduce the file size to 2-3 GB, then users are going to continue uploading images, and the file is going to grow again. What did you gain in the meantime? Were you able to lease it out until SQL Server needed it again? Delete the data, rebuild your indexes, and leave the file size alone. SQL Server will reuse that space. A big file is not a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow below steps

- Take a backup of your DB
- Check your .mdf file size
- Delete the records containing images(as per your need)
- Again Check your .mdf file size
- Shrink your DB file
- Once again Check your .mdf file size
- Now Rebuild/Re-organize indexes as per fragmentation in DB
- Finally check your .mdf file size(must be reduced).....

Answer (score 2):

Yes, deleting the unused images will free up space inside your DB files.  To actually reduce the size of those files you will have to `SHRINK` them after the images have been deleted.  Here's a link to the MS [Technet site](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189035.aspx) for this process.  Shrinking the files will most likely introduce internal fragmentation into your tables and indexes.  A thorough `REBUILD` would be appropriate afterwards.  On a 10GB database, once a year, this shouldn't be an undue burden.

Comment: ...and if you do a thorough rebuild, the files will grow again. Much better off deleting the data, rebuilding, and leaving the file size as is (since you are going to have to grow again anyway).

Comment: What is the best way to delete the image field content? Just update it with NULL value?

Comment: @Level1Coder sure, it wasn't clear from the question whether you were deleting rows or just deleting values. It may make more sense for you to keep these images in a related table instead of the main table - then you can delete the rows there instead of deleting the off-row data in the main table. Might be easier for maintenance in the long run (also allows you to add columns like expiration so that you can automate cleanup).